# How do you bind variables in cx_Oracle with Python3.x?

Tags: python, sql, oracle, selenium, cx-oracle

I hope you can help me out as I've been stuck with this for a while. First time posting here and what not. I'll preface this by saying I'm an Automation tester who has a bit of Python experience but I am no expert.

I've been racking my brain trying to get around this problem and I don't know whether it's a limitation of cx_Oracle or what but I can't find anyone with a similar problem. I have pretty much no prior experience with cx_Oracle.

So, here's a little example of what I'm trying to do. I can't post the whole thing because it's a bit of a mess with how much I've altered it and moved things around. I'm just going to try and do a really basic version of what I have;

```
    def test(self):
        #Driver is set up
        var1 = driver.find_element_by_name('blah').text
        var1 = str(var1)
        #Do some other stuff on the page
        return var1

    def foo():
        #Setup cx_Oracle and connect to DB
        sql = ('SELECT value FROM table WHERE ref = :1')
        c.execute(sql, (var1,)
        #Verify the results of the query

    class testcase(unittest.Testcase):
        def test_case(self):
            setUp(self)
            test(self)
            foo()
```

There are no error messages or anything like that. It just doesn't seem to see the value of the variable. When I hardcode the value of var1 it works and returns results as if I had queried the DB through DBeaver.

I've tried putting everything in the same function and get the same results.

I tried passing var1 around as below and still get the same results:

```
    def test(self):
        #Driver is set up
        var1 = driver.find_element_by_name('blah').text
        #Do some other stuff on the page
        return var1

    def foo(var1):
        #Setup cx_Oracle and connect to DB
        sql = ('SELECT value FROM table WHERE ref = :1')
        c.execute(sql, (var1,))
        #Verify the results of the query

    class testcase(unittest.Testcase):
        def test_case(self):
            setUp(self)
            var1 = test(self)
            print (var1)
            foo(var1)
```

I've been using [this as a reference for binding variables](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/dsl/prez-python-queries-101587.html) but none of the methods work for me.

So, in summary, I have 2 functions and I want to pass a variable from one to the other BUT cx_Oracle doesn't seem to like it. I chose cx_Oracle because pyodbc and pypyodbc didn't seem to want to connect to the Oracle 10g DB I'm trying to talk to. I'm even open to using another tool if anyone knows a better one?

If you need any more details, let me know.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can use `string.format` to build the sql

```
def foo(var1):
    #Setup cx_Oracle and connect to DB
    sql = 'SELECT value FROM table WHERE ref = {}'.format(var1)
    c.execute(sql)
```

Comment: I *think* this has definitely helped. The problem now is that when var1 gets to foo() it has become a None type. So, something else has gone wrong somewhere. Any suggestions on why that might happen?

Comment: You need to assign the return value from calling test to var1 before calling `foo(var1)`  as in Stefan's answer. `var1 = test(self)`

Comment: Sorted it. I had somehow removed the return. I have no idea when or how but now it's working. THANKYOU SO MUCH.

Comment: @AutomaticFish glad to help!

Comment: Please use bind variables! Formatting the variable directly into the SQL statement is asking for issues like SQL injection and reduced performance.

Comment: SQL Injection is one of the biggest security risks in applications. Concatenation to create SQL statements should only be used (carefully) to join strings that are hard coded in the application.  It should never be used with user data.  Use binds as other people have said.

Comment: @AnthonyTuininga - It's a QA environment and there's only me using/creating the scripts so I don't think it's an issue in this case. It's not in any way connected to a live environment and it's fully backed up. Using bind variables did not work and I have no idea why!

Comment: @ChristopherJones Same as above :)

Answer (score 2):

When getting in to problems like this it helps a lot to insert a few print statements printing your variables before using them so you know you are actually using the correct ones.. Doing a bit of changes to your code:

```
def test(self):
    #Driver is set up
    var1 = str(driver.find_element_by_name('blah').text)
    #var1 is a local variable to function test

    #Do some other stuff on the page
    return var1

def foo(var1):
    #Setup cx_Oracle and connect to DB
    sql = ('SELECT value FROM table WHERE ref = :1')
    c.execute(sql, (var1,))
    #Verify the results of the query

class testcase(unittest.Testcase):
    def test_case(self):
        setUp(self)
        var1 = test(self)
        print (var1)
        foo(var1)
```

Comment: Thanks. That isn't the full code it was just to give an idea of what I'm trying to do. There's plenty of print statements in there haha. Thanks for tidying my code. Like I said, I'm not an expert so this helps!